# facebook comments box cant see others comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Ok I'm sure this has been addressed somewhere, but as it currently stands I couldnt figure out the solution or find one on google....

I am implementing Facebook's comments box and my code is essentially a copy-paste of what is on the site

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=417087715031519";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    </body>

    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="file:///A:/commentsbox.html" data-width="470"></div>
</html>
```

Problem is that when I log in from my account and comment, I can see my comments, when I log in from another test account, I can only see that test accounts comments, and when I log in from another test account, again I can only see its comments. What am I doing wrong?

Note that I currently have this up on localhost and my APP is in test mode.

Comment: Check your configuration of application, it will be in Sandbox mode, disable it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had a fundamental misunderstanding when asking this question. Test users cant view each others comments (which is how I was testing the comments box)..